# what is the cause of this error message "Error: Cannot find module '../models'" from nodejs+elasrticsearch github repo

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup node.js and Elasticsearch together in a docker container,

I've been following  this [post](https://blog.logrocket.com/full-text-search-with-node-js-and-elasticsearch-on-docker/) to the letter,until to the section of launching the application

when I type

```
 docker-compose up
```

I keep getting  this node.js error that is saying models module is not found

```
tqd-node         | { Error: Cannot find module '../models'
```

this is the first few lines of the error message

```
tqd-elasticsearch is up-to-date
Starting tqd-node ... done
Attaching to tqd-elasticsearch, tqd-node
tqd-elasticsearch | WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver
tqd-node         |
tqd-node         | > nodejselastic@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
tqd-node         | > pm2-runtime start ./src/main.js --name node_app
tqd-node         |
tqd-node         | 2019-12-14T23:09:56: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
tqd-node         | 2019-12-14T23:09:56: PM2 log: App [node_app:0] starting in -fork mode-
tqd-node         | 2019-12-14T23:09:56: PM2 log: App [node_app:0] online
tqd-node         | { Error: Cannot find module '../models'
tqd-node         |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
tqd-node         |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:51:29)
```

so I downloaded the full code from [this GitHub repository(the-quotes-database)](https://github.com/micheleriva/the-quotes-database)

but I still got the same error

I did try to change the path in controller file [here](https://github.com/micheleriva/the-quotes-database/blob/master/src/server/controllers/index.js)

```
  const model = require("../models");
```

I thought maybe it needs the full c:// path, but that didn't change the error message.
when I do hover over models in VSC editor it shows that it is the correct path.

**so my question is :** is this a bug in the repo or is the issue with my windows docker configuration?

I successfully managed to create simple python containers with docker,
 so I'm not sure what is the root cause of this error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:** I will answer here in case anyone finds a similar issue.

I installed docker and downloaded the files and repeated the steps on my Ubuntu laptop and it worked!

so the downloaded files were not prepared to work on Windows, it is not a bug in the repo if you have Linux.